# The set of functions from a set to a set is finite if given sets are finite?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A,B$ be finite sets, Can we conclude that $B^A $( the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ ) is finite ?

if we assume $|A| = m $ and $|B| = n $, then we are being asked number of functions from $A$ to $B$ which is $(n+1)^m $ and so $B^A$ is finite. is this correct?

Comment: @Regret happens even to the best of us!

Answer (score 1):

$B^A$ is finite it's a correct answer its cardinal is exactly $|B|^{|A|}$ and so the first part is not correct.

> Let $A=\{x_1,\cdots,x_m\}$ and define $\phi:B^A\to B^m$ , $$\phi(f)=(f(x_1),\cdots,f(x_m))$$
>   **claim**: $\phi$ is bijective.

*Proof* :

- $\phi$ is one to one, suppose that $\phi(f)=\phi(g)$ then the equality between the tuples gives us $f(x_i)=g(x_i)$ for all $i\in [1,m]$ so $\forall a\in A\ \  f(a)=g(a)$ which gives us the equality of functions hence $f=g$.
- $\phi$ is onto given a tuple $b=(b_1,\cdots,b_m)\in B^m$ let's consider $f_b$ defined form $A$ to $B$ by $f(x_i)=b_i$ for every $i$ hence $\phi(f_b)=b$. so $\phi$ is onto.

As  a consequence of this claim we have $|B^A|=|B^m|=|B|^m$.

I assumed that you already proved in course that $B^m$ is finite and you know its cardianl, this can be done by induction using the basic relation $|A\times B|=|A|\times |B|$